# Is it possible to make the PC as a web storage?

Tags: html, web

I am looking for a space storage for my website because my hosting server has a limited space storage and my question is... Is it possible to make the PC as a web storage?
Thank u for the answers...

Comment: Why you want to do that? There are better option available for storage. I will suggest to use Amazon S3 for storage. Using PC as a storage device for your web server is not a good idea. This is worst idea if somebody thought of it.

Comment: you would need to set up your pc AS a webserver and either host from it, or have it accessible by the main server, which, IMO is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  ownCloud 8 with Ubuntu Server operating system.

You will need to have a static IP address as well.

But this is a very bad idea for what you are trying to do.

Its always recommended to use real time cloud servers instead of your pc

for example :

Use
Youtube to host your videos , 
Imgur to host images,
GoogleDrive to host files

There are lot of other options you can think